# Is there a good way to consistently position a TextView on an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `ImageView`, which is intended to take up the whole screen if it matters, and I intend to put several labels on it with `TextView`s. I need these labels to correspond to a precise position on the image.

I tried setting the margins in xml, but that won't work because the `dp` won't convert between devices. I am aware that I can set positions as a percentage of the screen size programatically but this poses a few problems:

1. I don't want to solve this problem programatically.
2. The aspect ratio of the image is being maintained, so on most screens there will be a little bit of white space given that the screen is a different shape from the image. Also, the app is not full screen, so the notification bar takes up space. This white space and the notification bar's space makes a percentage of the screen different from a percentage of the image.

   How can i position `TextView`'s on an `ImageView` in such a way that they will be in exactly the same spot (relative to the image) on every device?

Comment: You can use FrameLayout and programtically set the TextView's position by calling setX(), setY();

Comment: @David how does this work?

Comment: just that simple as said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out myself:

`text.setX((int) (img.getX()+(img.getWidth()*pct)/100)`

and the same for y, where `text` is the TextView, `img` is the ImageView, and `pct` is the location as a percentage of the image. Another problem is that this can't be called in `onCreate()`. I called it in `onWindowFocusChanged()`.

To prevent your ImageView from being a different shape from the Image, which would break this solution, you can do:

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

and be sure to set at least one of the dimensions as `wrap_content`.